# PHP echo tables in a database and download them as CSV files

Tags: php, database, csv, hyperlink

I'm new to PHP and am trying to create a small snippet of code that reads the tables in my database and allows the user to download the tables into a CSV file.

So far, I've been able to connect to my database and echo through the tables

```
 // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed1: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// SQL query
$sql = "SHOW TABLES IN `abc1`";

// perform the query and store the result
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// if the $result not False, and contains at least one row
     if($result !== false) {

       // if at least one table in result
       if($result->num_rows > 0) {
       // traverse the $result and output the name of the table(s)
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                 echo '<br />'. $row['Tables_in_abc1'];
            }
       }
 else echo 'There is no table in "tests"';
 }
 else echo 'Unable to check the "tests", error - '. $conn->error;


 $conn->close();
 ?>
```

Now I'd like to turn each table into a link so when the user clicks on it, they will be able to download the table's data into a CSV file.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

This should be a comment but I'm not high enough of a level to leave one. You should check out PHPExcel.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

It comes with numerous examples which should help you achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: That library is dead, however, there's a link on the Github page to a newer and active replacement - PHPSpreadsheet. https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Answer (score 3):

You could stream the data to the client like this:

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=file.csv');

$stdout = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    fputcsv($stdout, $row);
}
fclose($stdout);
```

or write to a file:

```
$filePath = __DIR__ .'/tmp.csv'; // for instance current folder
$fh = fopen($filePath, 'w+');
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    fputcsv($fh, $row);
}
fclose($fh);
```

and then send the find to client:

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=file.csv');

readfile($filePath);
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php